# When does a public company report a balance sheet?

Tags: stocks, india, accounting

As 31st March is the last day of the financial year in India. I was browsing some data and found that there are many companies that have not reported their balance sheets for 2013-2014. Is there a certain deadline? Or when are these reports usually made public?

Comment: Are you asking about the rules in India or the USA?

Comment: I am asking about rules in India

Answer (score 1):

a company might have a financial year that differs from the norm. for example tata might decide to use january-december for accounting purposes. a company thus will report whenever it's financial year is ending. in the case of public companies due to investor pressure they usually  report each quarter or semi-annually try checking the company's website.